# Java DateTimeFormatter: Print milliseconds to 3 places only if not 0

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I'm trying to do something seemingly quite simple, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

I want to parse certain Strings as LocalTime and then print them in the desired format. What I want is:

1. Always print at least `HH:mm:ss` (`13:00:00` prints as `13:00:00`).
2. Only print milliseconds if they != 0 (`13:45:20` and `13:45:20.000` both print as `13:45:20`)
3. If printing milliseconds, *always* print them to three places. (`13:45:20.01` prints as `13:45:20.010`)

It seems like it should be possible using optionals in the DateTimeFormatter, as per the documentation of `optionalStart`:

```
All elements in the optional section are treated as optional.
During formatting, the section is only output if data is available in the
{@code TemporalAccessor} for all the elements in the section.
During parsing, the whole section may be missing from the parsed string.
```

However, enforcing the 3 decimal places for millis seems to bypass the optional aspect i.e. `.000` gets printed when millis == 0:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral('.')
            .appendValue(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .toFormatter();

System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalTime.parse("12:45:00"))); // Outputs 12:45:00.000, bad!
System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalTime.parse("12:45:00.000"))); // Outputs 12:45:00.000, bad!
System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalTime.parse("12:45:00.010")));  // Outputs 12:45:00.010, good!
```

It can of course be done via conditionals, manually checking if millis != 0, but what I want to know is if this is possible to achieve via less explicit means.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: No, there is no support for what you are trying. `LocalTime.toString()` will get you close, but will leave out the seconds if both seconds and fraction of second are null, so just print `12:45`. Your best friend for your exact requirements may be an old-fashioned `if` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion lies with the behaviour of `optionalStart`. You expect it to truncate millisecond values that are zero (as you consider the millisecond value to not exist). However, `optionalStart` only looks at the presence of date time components, not the value (therefore the "existance" of the millisecond component of the time is never missing). Think of it as the difference between a timestamp without milliseconds vs a timestamp with zero milliseconds.

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValue` does not claim to truncate decimal places (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-), so to get the behaviour you seek, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-, e.g.

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() 
.appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2) 
.appendLiteral(':') 
.appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2) 
.appendLiteral(':') 
.appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2) 
.optionalStart() 
.appendFraction(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true) 
.toFormatter();
```

Note: You added the decimal place as a literal, which means that the formatter has no way of understanding that you want the milliseconds as fractions. In general, the library has to provide the decimal place if you want to treat values as fractions instead of whole numbers.

**Edit:**
Apologies to @AMterp for not quite matching the expected behaviour. Specifically, 3 decimal places should be displayed unless the millisecond component is zero.

To achieve this, unfortunately I can't see a way to get `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` to behave this way (none of the built in functions support this and the class is `final` so you cannot override implementations). Instead, I can suggest two options:

1. Always display 3 decimal places and run `.replace(".000", "")` afterwards, or
2. Remove the millisecond component of the timestamp if it is zero (I.e. set to `null`)

Comment: Was just about to post that snippet as an answer. Note that `.optionalStart()` is no longer needed, as `minWidth` is `0`.

Comment: And that [decimal separator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) is a localizable entity, with a FULL STOP `.` used in some locales such as the United States, and a COMMA `,` used in other locales such as some in Europe. So the separator should not be hard-coded in a formatter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, really appreciate the answer! Unfortunately, this snippet/`appendFraction` method doesn't quite fulfill my third requirement of printing millis to three places like the example I gave of "`13:45:20.01` prints as `13:45:20.010`" (I should have worded it more clearly to say I *always* want it to three places if millis != 0), as this will print `13:45:20.01`. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: No worries @Woodz, thanks for taking the time! While not the answer I was hoping for, it does answer my question.